# Display bare image from a SP List in web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, modern-experience

I am working on migrating very old Sharepoint 2013 sites to O365 and the new modern experience.  I have a need to display a simple image on a page that would come from a list.  The list has a hyperlink/Picture column and a flag indicating if it is the active item.

In older Sharepoint we simply added a list webpart and then filtered it for the active row and then only displayed the image column.  With the right web part settings we could easily have it simply display the image without a title or any other decorations like column headers, sorting, indicators, etc.

With Sharepoint online we haven't figured out how to remove the extra stuff and simply display the image.

Is this possible anymore without custom JS or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The list web part in SharePoint online has no option to change the display column.

As a workaround, we could add another web part called "List properties" to connect to a list web part on the same page and display specific properties of the list on your page dynamically.

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Comment: ... an interesting idea, and I looked into it, but then I have to display the list on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I ended up implementing was to use a PowerApp.  It seems like a crazy overkill, but I created a simple Canvas application with a single page that has an Image control on it.  I then set a query to return the image field of the first matching record in the list.  This seems to work well.  The only negative that I see so far is that the image seems to take slightly longer to load than I'd expect.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, you could accept your reply as answer.